# Shopware Basic settings are not displayed ("Basic settings are loading")

Tags: php, shopware, php-7.0

I installed the Shopware 5.4.6 community shop. 
I now wanted to make changes in the basic settings what is answered with "Basic settings will be loaded" (BTW i use german version so i got "Grundeinstellungen wird geladen").
All other points can be displayed without problems.

PHP Version 7.0.31, Linux 3.16.0-6-amd64, Apache, Shopware 5.4.6

backend UI shows no errors in Shopware logs

backend UI shows shows nothing in the system log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved / Done / Solved / Workaround:

Tried different things. Also read the apache error logs. did not help.

How I got it work:

have uploaded and installed a fresh shop in a subfolder of the shop. this time the basic settings were accessible.

So I just wanted to give it a try again (in the home folder)

So i deleted (all inside the shop home) and uploaded again. istalled. and even then the basic settings were accessible.

I noticed:
during these installations the assigned rights for individual files were no longer required / required / remindet during the installation.

may because I had recursively set writing permissions in the shop folder (sometime yesterday when trying around).

I have not tested now if the error occurs again, if I do not give this home folder at the beginning writing permissions recursivly for php. uploaud just takes too long at this lame server. it took a whole hour to empty the content folder (FTP access).

Too bad the shopware 5.4.6 could had no error messages. Maybe too rare a case.

Comment: You need to find time and check documentation, there is a lot of useful information: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/debugging/